# Is it possible in Chrome to disallow Developer mode for enterprise-installed extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, enterprise, group-policy

Is there a way to disallow Developer mode for a specific enterprise-installed extension, or for that matter, all extensions?

Tried using DeveloperToolsDisabled policy, but that did something else -- disallowed the Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) and JavaScript console (Ctrl+Shift+J) menu items.  But that did not apply to extensions.

Comment: When DeveloperToolsDisabled is true, can you use `chrome://inspect`? In either case, being able to use devtools when devtools are disabled sounds like a bug, the best place to report that is at https://crbug.com/new

Comment: Yes, can use chrome://inspect/#extensions and bring up devtools for the extension.

Comment: For others, Thomas has reported the issue at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460543